# Invoke WCF Workflow Service using different endpoint addresses

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation

I created a Workflow Foundation workflow which will eventually invoke another Workflow Service. I added the call to this service by dragging the appropriate shape from the toolbox onto the designer. The shape was available because I added the Workflow Service as a service reference as recommended.

How can I specify a specific endpoint address for this web service? I can't find a way to programmatically specify the address.
The workflow always uses the address specified in the web.config. But based on certain conditions I want to use different addresses.

**Edit**

Here is a picture I created to illustrate the problem:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Look for the place where you make a call to the Workflow Service. Somewhere there you define a client. It should look something like this:

```
client.InvokeService(); // or whatever method you call;
```

If you want to change address you should change endpoint address before this call, ideally when you define the client:

```
client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("http://something.com/service.wsdl");
```

But keep in mind that this is not recommended practice. If you intend to change it programmatically it's better to get rid of services section in your web.config completely and set properties programmatically when creating client.

Comment: I'm using the studio-generated shape from the toolbox to call the webservice. The web service send activity was generated because I added the service reference to the project. When dragging the shape to the workflow there is no way of specifying the endpoint address, except for the web.config.